# What is the syntax for using __bridge cast in conjunction with static_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, automatic-ref-counting, llvm, objective-c++

I tried below, but compiler does not understand it:

```
//Foo.mm
id anObjOfTypeFoo;
Foo* obj = (Foo*) anObjOfTypeFoo; //ERROR: must use __bridge

Foo* obj = (__bridge Foo*) anObjOfTypeFoo; //OKAY

Foo* obj = static_cast<__bridge Foo*> (anObjOfTypeFoo); //ERROR

Foo* obj = __bridge (static_cast<Foo*> (anObjOfTypeFoo)); //ERROR
```

Since Objective-C code is effectively compiled by a C++ compiler for a .mm compilation unit, it should really not have problems to bridge the casts of C++. Can someone shed light on this please?

Comment: Well, __bridge offers a cast between Objective-C pointers and Core Foundation objects. Why would you need a static_cast anyways?

Comment: My core logic is written in C++ and I'm just putting a UI code on top of it for iOS client. And static_cast is preferred over normal C-style cast because of many reasons, prominent being given its' safety. [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx ]

Comment: Please correct me if I am mistaken, but I do not think you can static_cast a Core Foundation object to an Objective C object with a simple static_cast. It used to be that way (well, it used to be a normal C-style cast), but the new ARC policies enforce __bridge'ing.

Comment: Even I don't know what is the correct way to handle static_cast with __bridge. :( Also not sure why someone added automatic-ref-counting to this question. lol

Comment: __bridge was actually mainly driven by ARC. From what I understand, and I did a detailed write up here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207960/arc-bridge-modifiers-demystified/14207961#14207961 ) about __bridge modifiers, __bridge is almost like a plain-old cast. So mixing them together doesn't make sense.

Comment: `Foo* obj = (Foo*) anObjOfTypeFoo; //ERROR: must use __bridge` That's not possible. Unless `Foo` is not an Objective-C class. If `Foo` is an Objective-C class, there should be no error with or without the cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too bad static_cast come from C++, it doesn't understand Objective-C classes. You can't even cast from `NSString` to `NSMutableString`.