# Not hearing sound from AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

Can't figure out what is wrong here or what I am missing to hear sound.  It builds fine with no errors.

From what I am reading, it has something to do with ARC.... ?
But when I look under the "Build Settings:  Apple LLVM 7.0:  ARC" ARC is listed as "NO"

---

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

---

.m

```
@synthesize player;

...

NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"abc" withExtension:@"m4a"];

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

[player play];
```

---

This works:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1005);
```

---

Trying this: ([ARC __bridge modifiers demystified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207960/arc-bridge-modifiers-demystified))

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSLog(@"Filename:  %@", soundFile);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge  CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], & soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

This crashes out with: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
...so looking in I can't see a filename... Filename:  (null)

Comment: Try this way to get sound's path url: NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" 
                                                          ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL * soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

Comment: @azimov Why? The OP's code to get the URL is fine.

Comment: how and where is the player declared. you have to retain the player while you use it. e.g. via a strong property

Comment: did the "strong" in property but same nothing.  Suspend a thread perhaps? ... tried and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to goto:

```
Project:
Targets:
Build Phases:
Copy Bundle Resources: and add the abc.m4a file to it.
```

The other files I needed were there except that one.

More info:  [NSBundle pathForResource is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949368/nsbundle-pathforresource-is-null)

Comment: Some simple debugging would have shown you that `soundFileURL` was `nil` in your original code. Which also means that `player` was probably `nil` as well. Making use of the `error` parameter would have helped there as well.